# GNU Automake - How does dist_bin_SCRIPTS work and can I change it?

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu, automake

In a Makefile.am file I have come across the variable assignment `dist_bin_SCRIPTS = foo`

From this [website](https://readme.phys.ethz.ch/documentation/managing_a_software_package_with_the_gnu_autotools/) under the heading **Makefile.am** it says it installs the script in the `/usr/local/bin` directory.

It also says there are ways to define your own values (directories to install to)... In my case I would like to change it to install the script foo in `/etc/bash_completion.d`, does anybody know how to do this?

I've tried looking at the automake manual but I couldn't find out the required info sadly.

All help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bin_SCRIPTS installs to /usr/local/bin is because `bindir` is predefined already (with many layers of defaults). So,

```
foodir = ${sysconfdir}/bash_completion.d
foo_DATA = mycompletion.sh
```

is the fast way without parametrization from configure (but still overridable at make-time.)

Comment: Could you explain why `dist_` is not needed in front of `foo_DATA`?

Comment: dist_ is only needed explicitly in few cases, in particular if the file is generated by some tooling but you still want to put a copy in the tarball.
If you don't generate the file, but rather have it in the source repository, just `bin_SCRIPTS` would work just as fine as `foo_DATA`.